# What could the Jedi have done with Anakin other than train him?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, jedi-training

There was a lot of discussion at the end of Episode I about training Anakin.

Given that he was highly Force sensitive and there were unknown Sith around, it would seem very dangerous not to take him in and try to give him some discipline. Did they have any other options? If so, what?

> Just look at the flowers Anakin?

Comment: Would it be harsh to suggest drowning him?

Comment: I feel like there's a question hidden in this one (that I don't know enough SW lore to delve into): Could they have taught him a non-violent form of the Jedi way? For instance, if they had foreseen from the start that he was at risk of falling to the dark side, could he have been trained as a pacifist Jedi monk, who doesn't use a lightsaber or intervene in conflicts?

Comment: @recognizer There were the [AgriCorps](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Agricultural_Corps)

Comment: @RogueJedi Hmm... the last paragraph of that wiki article suggests that AgriCorps members weren't very well prepared to resist the temptations of the dark side :)

Answer (score 4):

The strong implication seems to be that unless a Jedi is given at least a modicum of training, their force powers never really assert themselves other than as "jedi-like reflexes" and prophetic dreams that they won't really understand. Note that Luke was in his late teens before he even met Obi-Wan and although he was considered to be among the finest pilots of his generation, he'd never been able to do so much as lift a pebble with his Jedi powers.

Yoda is **emphatic** that Qui-gon shouldn't begin training Anakin until after a decision has been made on his future, the strong implication being that once that line has been crossed, it would be far more dangerous to leave him in-situ.

Had they returned Anakin to Tatooine (or sent him to Naboo) he would likely have led a remarkably mundane life as a hotshot test pilot or a fabulous engineer. There's no special reason to believe that he would have been able to control his powers on his own, or be much of a threat to those around him.

Comment: But with the sith re asserting themselves he would be rich pickings for a Master.

Comment: At that point (Counsil's decision on Anakin) the Sith were still thought extinct.

Comment: @tilley31: are you sure?  I thought Qui-gon had told the council about Darth Maul before they interviewed Anakin.  (But it's been some years since I last saw episode 1.)

Comment: I also haven't watched it for a while. I thought the Jedi had CONFIRMED the Sith were back in Qui Gon's funeral.

Comment: He was definitely not in his late teens when he met Obi-Wan. I think the actor who played him was like 8... his character was meant to be like 10 or 12 though.

Comment: @Derek he says Luke was in his teens, not anni

Comment: Bah, good catch.